# Laravel 4 - Connect to other database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I want to connect to another database sometimes.

I created a config.php with the database connection data.

But how can i tell laravel to connect to this database insted of using the config/database.php?

For example when using the `Schema` class.

Since no one seems to understand what i want.

**I DON'T want to use the config/database.php, i want to use a different config file on a different location.**

Comment: Since you're not giving any specific code to "port", take a look [here](http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?pid=6387) in case it answers your question.

Comment: What code? As i said i want to create a additional config.php with the database settings and connect to this. The question is how can i tell laravel to use this config insted of the config/database.php.

Comment: The linked page shows how to add multiple database configs to database.php, and how to select which one to use to connect to/query.

Comment: I appreciate that you try to help me but i wrote it 2 times now. I DON'T want to use the config/database.php. I want to create an additional config.php file at a different location.

Comment: Well.. Even if i would use the config/database.php. How can i use the Schema class with the other database then? DB:connection is not what i want to use. I need the Schema class. Seems like this is not possible?

Comment: Then you'd just use `Schema::connection('foo')->create('users', function($table)...` to use the 'foo' database.

Comment: Okay thanks that works. Dunno why there is no info about that. But there is no way to use another config?

Comment: Since i use a modul system that is not what i want. I need to specify the config at the needed point ;/. Not sure why you deleted your last comment :P

Comment: Not to my knowledge then, but I've never mucked around in the code to see if it's possible. Maybe someone else here knows.

Comment: Okay. Hopefully anyone has an idea. Thank you anyways :)

Comment: Deleted my comment since you need to include it in a specific way to make it work so was looking in the docs to get it right, was a bit simple to just say "include it" :) If it's not an option, I'll check it out later.

Answer (score 60):

It sounds like you figured this out. Here's how I'd accomplish it anyway for other people coming in, or in case something useful is here for you.

**First**, Add a second connection in `app/config/database.php`. Note: That file path may change depending on your environment.

```
<?php
return array(
    'connections' => array(
        'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'database'  => 'database1',
            'username'  => 'user1',
            'password'  => 'pass1'
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),

        'mysql2' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'database'  => 'database2',
            'username'  => 'user2',
            'password'  => 'pass2'
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),
    ),
);
```

**Second**, in your code, you can use (as mentioned) the 2nd connection where you would like:

`Schema::connection('mysql2')->create('users', function($table) {})`

There's more documentation on this - see [Accessing Connections](http://laravel.com/docs/database#accessing-connections).

**Eloquent ORM**
You can define the variable for "connection" in an eloquent class to set which connection is used. That's noted in the [Basic Usage](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#basic-usage) section.

See that variable on [here on Github](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L28) and the method which you can set to set the connection dynamically [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L2251).

**Edit**
The OP has made it clear that they do not wish to use the config/database.php file for config.

However without explaining further, I can't comment. I'm happy to help - sounds like it would be useful to know **why** the config/database.php file can't/shouldn't be used, as this can help us ascertain the problem and create a useful solution.

Comment: I use a ModulSystem. Tha'ts the reason ;)

Comment: What about validation? For example the "exists" validation rule. How do you tell it to use some other connection/database?

Comment: You can over-ride what connection it set in the [Validation service provider](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.1/src/Illuminate/Validation/ValidationServiceProvider.php#L30). I don't know about if you need to switch between database connections. You'll have to dig into the code and do some extending/over-riding.

Answer (score 12):

I believe you want to implement some kind of logical sharding where databases would be dynamically created.

In such scenario in laravel you can dynamically add a database config, like below

```
$conn = array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'DATABASE',
    'username'  => 'USERNAME',
    'password'  => 'SOME_PASSWORD',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
);

Config::set('database.connections.DB_CONFIG_NAME', $conn);
```

Now to connect via eloquent

```
MODEL::on('DB_CONFIG_NAME')->WHAT_EVER('1');
```

Incase of Query Builder you can do

```
$DB = DB::connection('DB_CONFIG_NAME');
```

use `$DB->select()` for querying now.

Hope this would help devs looking for a possible solution for this question

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with Laravel 5.2, DatabaseManager.php:239 throws exception 'Database [database.connections.DB_CONFIG_NAME] not configured.' I also tried `App::make('config')->set('database.connections.DB_CONFIG_NAME', $conn)`, with the same result. Any idea?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I missed the simple fact that you don't need the `database.connections.` prefix when referencing the configured connection later. For some reason that error message completely threw me off.

Answer (score 11):

Remember that Laravel 4 is actually a collection of components, and you can use these components solo.

https://github.com/illuminate/database

There is an example here that shows off how interacting with the Capsule class works:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;

$capsule = new Capsule;

$capsule->addConnection([
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'database',
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => 'password',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
]);

// Set the event dispatcher used by Eloquent models... (optional)
use Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher;
use Illuminate\Container\Container;
$capsule->setEventDispatcher(new Dispatcher(new Container));

// Set the cache manager instance used by connections... (optional)
$capsule->setCacheManager(...);

// Make this Capsule instance available globally via static methods... (optional)
$capsule->setAsGlobal();

// Setup the Eloquent ORM... (optional; unless you've used setEventDispatcher())
$capsule->bootEloquent();
```

This is a bunch of bootstrapping that you'll need to run, so tuck it away somewhere in a function or method.

But, its absolutely possible.

Answer (score 5):

There is a simpler solution. If you are using Larave 4 there is an option that worked for me. Recently they added $table variable that you can specify in your model. Refer to [this link](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent).

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'my_users';

}
```

If you are using MySQL, you can do the following:

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'mydbname.my_users';

}
```

If you are using SQL Server, you can do this:

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'mydatabase..my_users';

}
```

My Config file had DB1 specified but I created a model which wants to access DB2 in the same MySQL host. So this was a quick and dirty way to accomplish this.

Now I don't fully leverage Eloquent ORM all the time so this "hack" may not work with Many to Many or one to Many Eloquent methods.

One another idea I had but I didn't actually try was creating a stored procedure (routine) in DB1 and inside of that routine I can access DB2 tables by querying link this:

```
SELECT * from db2.mytable where id = 1;
```

Comment: If you are happy with having/able to have the same user access both databases, this is a beautifully elegant solution.

Answer (score 3):

To use a config file in another location, say `src/config`:

```
use Config;


$this->dbConfig = Config::get('appname::dbInfo.connections.test');
$this->database = $this->dbConfig['database'];
$this->username= $this->dbConfig['username'];
$this->password= $this->dbConfig['password'];
```

Where `dbInfo` is a simple php file in your app's `src/config` directory returning an array containing the element `connections` which is an array of database properties.

You can tell Laravel to use an external config file using:

```
Config::set("database.connections.test", $this->dbConfig);
DB::connection("test");
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit `bootstrap/start.php` file and add your machine name (open terminal: `hostname`).

Add your machine to $env,

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
    'mymachine' => array('mymachine.local'),
));
```

1. Create a new path at `'app/config/mymachine'`
2. Add a copy of `database.php` with new config params.