# Laravel 4 Query Builder with different databases

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-4, query-builder

I've been using Laravel 4 for a while with success until I found a recent problem. I'm using an alternate DB connection to retrieve a list of products. My problem is that I don't find a way to create a connection like `DB::connection('foo')` and implement my query in a query builder style. I assume its some IoC behavior but my lack of understanding of the inner framework's code keeps me away from the answer

Thank you all

Answer (score 4):

1. Add a second connection in app/config/database.php

   ```
       'mysql2' => array(
           'driver'    => 'mysql',
           'host'      => 'localhost',
           'database'  => 'database2',
           'username'  => 'user2',
           'password'  => 'pass2'
           'charset'   => 'utf8',
           'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
           'prefix'    => '',
   ```
2. Now use that second connection:

   DB::connection('mysql2')->select('where...');

Comment: Yes, that what the documentation says.. but what I want is something like `DB::connection('mysql2')->table('foo')->join(...)->where(array(...))` in a Query Builder fashion

Comment: The example I put above it's pseudocode and doesn't work. With @shift answer all I can do is write a SQL command between quotes in the select method. What I want (and now I think can't be done) is not to loose the Query Builder properties when working with extra db connections. It doesn't have any sense to me to use a string query if you already have Eloquent and query builder there to help you

Comment: @AlwinKesler you can do that. See [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17410049/laravel-4-connect-to-other-database/17412301#17412301), which I think Shift copied from? - My answer has some more details on doing what you'd like. You actually answered your own question. After setting up the config for another MySQL connection, you can then use `DB::connection('mysql2')->table('foo')->join(...)->where(array(...))` exactly as you said. **Note** that you can't do Joins across different DBs.

Comment: Are you saying `DB::connection('mysql2')->table('foo')...` gives you an error?

Comment: I found the problem.. my "pseudocode" guess was right. The problem was with the foreign server which had a mysql 4.1+ password issue that I was attributing to the laravel alternative connection. Thank you all

Answer (score 3):

The proper way to accomplish this is `DB::connection('mysql2')->table('foo')->join(...)->where(array(...))`

My problem was outside the scope of this question.
Thank you all.