# How to change the connection info for Laravel 4 when using the redis driver?

Tags: php, caching, redis, laravel, laravel-4

I am using `redis` as the driver for caching data. The database configuration of Laravel has the ability to define the **Redis** connection information.

```
  'redis'       => array(
    'cluster' => true,
    'default' => array(
        'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
        'port'     => 6379,
        'database' => 0,
    ),
),
```

But if I wanted to have multiple connections defined and use a specific `connection` to use for the cache, how can I do this on Laravel 4. There is no connection configuration on cache.php where I can specify the redis connection name. It currently has a `connection` config that will be used if the cache driver is `database`.

**EDIT**

I just went through the Laravel code and when initializing the Redis Driver, it looks like Laravel is not looking into the connection. Is my understanding correct?

http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Cache.CacheManager.html#63-73

```
protected function createRedisDriver()
{
    $redis = $this->app['redis'];

    return $this->repository(new RedisStore($redis, $this->getPrefix()));
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laravel can handle multiple connections. See [this question/answer on adding/using multiple database connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17410049/laravel-4-connect-to-other-database/17412301#17412301).

Once you define multiple connections for redis, you'll need to do some leg work to access those somewhere in your code. That might look something like this:

```
$redisCache = App::make('cache'); // Assumes "redis" set as your cache
$redisCache->setConnection('some-connection'); // Your redis cache connection
$redisCache->put($key, $value');
```

**Edit**

I'll add a little here to give you an idea of how to do this so you don't need the connection logic everywhere:

Most simply, you can [bind an instance](http://laravel.com/docs/ioc) of your redis cache somewhere (perhaps a start.php or other app/start/*.php file) in your app:

```
App::singleton('rediscache', function($app){
    $redisCache = $app['cache'];
    $redisCache->setConnection('some-connection'); // Your redis cache connection
    return $redisCache;
});
```

Then, in your code, you can do this to cache:

```
$cache = App::make('rediscache');
$cache->put($key, $value); // Or whatever you need to do
```

You can also create a Service Provider if you have your [own application library](http://fideloper.com/laravel-4-application-setup-app-library-autoloading) of code. You can register 'rediscache' within there and then use it in the same way in your application.

Hope that helps as a start - there are other code architectures - using Dependency Injection and maybe a [repository](http://culttt.com/2013/07/08/creating-flexible-controllers-in-laravel-4-using-repositories/) to help organize your code further.

Comment: So, I will have to do this every time when adding or retrieving values on the cache. It would be easier to mention a connection information on `/app/config/cache.php` like how we have for the database cache.

Comment: Well there are code patterns that will allow you to streamline that but of code. I'm not sure on your level of knowledge about Laravel's IoC Container, dependency  injection and other code-architecture ideas. I suggest checking out using the "Repository Pattern" - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367159/laravel-repositories) and [here](http://culttt.com/2013/07/08/creating-flexible-controllers-in-laravel-4-using-repositories/). This hopefully can give you a start to see how you can write that logic once in your code and use it in many places.

Comment: I updated my response with some ideas on how you can make that code more re-usable.

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate your help