# Laravel using different connections for Inserting & Selecting data

Tags: laravel, connection

Is there anyway in the Laravel Eloquent to use two different connections, for inserting, updating and Selecting.

What i am trying to do is specify a connection when user is pulling the data from db, and another one while inserting or updating data.

I am wondering if it can be done with the Eloquent instead of defining connections everytime?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel 4 - Connect to other database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17410049/laravel-4-connect-to-other-database)

Comment: AFAIK the `on` method reported in the documentation is the only provided way (quite good IMO).

Comment: See [Implement automated read/write connections in Eloquent](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5)

Comment: This feature has recently been added but isn't documented yet. You can check the corresponding [commit](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/a3b0e87ae50b22a517c6daea85e824ae2f0e27c0) on how to use it.

Comment: @HolgerWeis Thanks, really good to know! So the answer is yes, with version 4.1

Comment: This feature has now been documented, see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible with Laravel 4.1. You can configure it in your `app/config/database.php` like so:

```
'mysql' => array(
    'read' => array(
        'host' => '192.168.1.1',
    ),
    'write' => array(
        'host' => '196.168.1.2'
    ),
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'database'  => 'database',
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => '',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
),
```

See the [Read / Write Connections](http://laravel.com/docs/database#read-write-connections) section in the Laravel database documentation.

Comment: what if I am using Eloquent outside of laravel how to configure read write connection.